# Refresh value from MySQL db on php page after clicking a submit button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

So all i need to do is refresh a variable displayed on a php page which is stored in a MySQL db. This value is an int which is subtracted by 1 everytime the submit button from a form is clicked. As i've opted to use AJAX to post the form the page isn't being refreshed, therefore the value isn't being updated along with the form submission.

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT codes_remaining FROM users WHERE email= '".$_SESSION['email']."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    if ($row['codes_remaining'] ==1 ) 
    {
    echo "You have ".$row['codes_remaining'].' code remaining';
    }
    else {
echo "You have ".$row['codes_remaining'].' codes remaining';
}
}
```

So this code just displays how many "codes" a person has left. I need this value to be refreshed once the submit button has been clicked from the form on the same page.

I'm using the following JavaScript to not refresh the page.

```
$("#form-submit").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        cache: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process-register.php',
        data: $("#form-register").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $("#output-div").html(response);
        }
        });
    });
```

Thanks,
LS

Comment: Your PHP code appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: So what exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: Well, I need the value to be refreshed once a submit button has been clicked. As I said, I'm using AJAX to process the form so at the moment the page doesn't refresh therefore the value doesn't refresh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to update the value, do it like this (jQuery is easiest):

```
$(".submit").click(function(event) { 
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).load('file.php',function(val){
        $('#output').text(val);
     });
 });
```

And in file.php:

```
<?php
    connect_to_db();
    $returned = get_info_from_db();
    echo $returned;
?>
```

The jQuery will grab the info on file.php and put it into #output.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It's just me, but why not use jQuery .load function?

```
    $("#form-submit").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).load('process-register.php');
    });
```

Maybe not ethical nor the correct way of doing this but everytime you click on #form-submit, it loads that file and therefore processes it everytime. Also note that if you load a file that uses MySQL connection yes has no `mysql_connect` or `mysql_select_db` configured, it obviously won't work. I've had that for quite some times.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'success', you could possibly just throw in

```
$("#WhereYouWantTheOutput").load("process-register.php");
```

That way whenever your submit succeeds, it'll also load the output for you. Just replace #WhereYouWantTheOutput with the name of where you want the output placed.